# Where to find Ethereum introduction material?

Tags: dapp-development

I'm from Chile were few people know about Bitcoin and even less about Ethereum.

I finished my studies last year in business engineering and I've been involved with the technology since 2013. Right now I'm working on my own ethereum project but first I need to teach people about it so I can get together a development team... I managed to contact the head of computer sciences in my university and explained everything and he got very interested and asked me to make some presentations.

The idea is to cover Bitcoin and Ethereum, awakening the interest of students and teachers to research more about the technology and it's capabilities to conform a research and development team in the university.

For this I've prepared a nice introduction to Bitcoin and some examples related to financial innovation sites. I want to do the same for Ethereum but it's a little more complex to explain and I've found little material. As examples I'm thinking about Augur and Slockit so far.

The audience will be mainly business and computer science people.

I had confirmation to make a 2nd conference dedicated to deeply cover the bitcoin protocol, so making a 3rd to deeply cover ethereum would't be impossible but lets focus on this one.

What would you suggest? Which topics would be essential but not too deep for an intro conference?

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite new to the idea and technology, so this is coming from a novice in the community. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seU7DykOxfc) might be a good example to start with, since it introduces the effect of cutting out the middle man. [Slides here.](http://www.slideshare.net/avsa/devcon-1-build-a-app-contract-and-design)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seU7DykOxfc

http://www.slideshare.net/avsa/devcon-1-build-a-app-contract-and-design